# phpinfo and php -v show different version on lion

Tags: php, osx-lion, version

I try to upgrade my php from 5.3.13 to 5.4.5
I've manually download source codes of php 5.4.5 and ./configure then sudo make install it.

after that, I run

```
php -v
```

it shows 5.4.5, while I run

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

it shows 5.3.13. what is the problem here and how to fix it. thanks

Comment: Are you sure the library that your web server (e.g. Apache) is the newest? Or try restarting the service? (I don't know apple but it's rather similar I think)

Comment: And are you using Homebrew or MacPorts?

Comment: @AlvinWong yes, I've restarted the service.

Comment: @Michael no, I didn't use neither of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess answer since I don't have a mac, but based on my Winodws experience this could only happen if you have 2 php executables and your CLI is using one and Apache is using the other.

In your `phpinfo()` output look for the table row `Loaded Configuration File`.

I'm on Windows so mine says `C:\server\php\5.4.3\php.ini` but of course yours will be different.

If this is not the path that you expect it to be using then you will need to make sure you change the path in your Apache's `httpd.conf` file.

Once you have found the httpd.conf file find the line: `PHPIniDir`

When you have found this line make sure it is pointing at the correct directory for the php.ini file and restart Apache.

I would also say to check the `LoadModule php5_module` line is also pointing at the correct file but the chances are that this will be ok if you were using php 5.3 before.

This answer does assume that you have installed the new php version in a different directory but this is all I can think of with the information you have provided.

Comment: I got your idea, but the problem is how to fix it. such as how to install latest php as apache module.

Answer (score 6):

I think I just came from the same problem. I'm using OSX lion and was installing PHP without brew or port was simply using PHP that came with the machine.

I was in need to install mcrypt module to the current php I'm using ( at that moment I didn't realize that there were 2 version of PHP on my machine, and forgot how I install it ), so I install homebrew and after that installing mcrypt using brew. After the installation, I open my browser and through phpinfo() I found that the PHP version is different with the one I install mcrypt module, and so cannot make the module to work.

This is what it showed in terminal :

```
Windo-MBP:~ herwindoartono$ php --version
PHP 5.3.23 (cli) (built: May  4 2013 06:43:49)
```

and from the browser ( local apache ), by opening a php page contain `phpinfo();` showing PHP **5.3.15 version.**. I don't know how I ended with different version on my machine, so I browse and I browse for solutions and found one :

**Changing a line in httpd.conf should change which php version I'm using**

This is how to change which PHP version to use, base on my experience :

- Edit your httpd.conf, by typing in terminal : `sudo subl /etc/apache2/httpd.conf` note: `subl` is for sublime text 2, else you can use `nano`.
- Find line `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`, comment it
- Add below that line : `LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php53/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`, for your case just change the `php53` to `php54`.
- Restart apache using terminal : `sudo apachectl restart`
- Test phpinfo() in browser, and it come out with version I intended to use.

Reference : https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/issues/448

I don't have much experience in PHP, but I hope this can solve your(or everyone else) problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the very same problem in Ubuntu 14.04, and I did the following:

1. from the root directory i looked for php.ini

   `find / -name php.ini`

I got two different files, which means I have two different versions of php installed, so

2. I removed all php versions

   `sudo apt-get -y purge php*`
3. then reintalled desired php version (in this case 5.6)

   `sudo apt-get install php5.6`

Comment: I did this now Nginx is broken. I only get 502 responses now. How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a simular situation, it was caused by different installation versions of php over time and the not updated searchpath in linux.

Investigate via `echo $PATH`.

Output for example: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin`

In my case the older version 5.5.9 was in a installation path referenced before the newest version 5.5.22.
5.5.9 was installled at `/usr/local/bin/` and 5.5.22 at `/usr/bin/`.

Adapt it to by moving the correct folder to before the wrong one, or better yet deinstall the old php version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `ubuntu` and your web server is `NGNIX`, and also you use of `php-fpm`, you should to change your `ngnix` config:

in `/etc/ngnix/sites-available` nano per your address and change the `fpm` version:

```
  location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
```

then restart your ngnix

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
```

now check your php version with `phpinfo()` and `php -v` on cli.